# Using Excel 2013 VBA can I dock my userform similar to other apps in Windows 7 or newer?

Tags: windows-7, excel, windows-8, userform, vba

When using Windows 7 or later, you can move the app to the left border of the screen and it will dock on the left of the screen taking up half the screen width; moving to the right side of the screen behaves the same as the left. Moving to the top of the screen, re-sizes the app to the entire window.

I have a userform that sets the application visibility to false when it is active (Application.Visible = False) in order to be able to use a browser to fill in the form data.

It would be great to be able to dynamically re-size the userform similar to the browser window so that I could have the browser on one side of my screen and the userform on the other.

Comment: I never knew you could do that!  I'm always dragging Excel or VBA part-way over and then resizing, and too often it snaps back to full-size.  So thanks. I hope you get an answer.

Comment: Thanks! So do I so vote me up!

Comment: Oh right!  Done.  I'm not very hopeful though.